# Multiple MySQL databases for Wordpress Multisite

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have created a freebie site for a local school where the students can have their own blog. I can get 150Mb MySQLdatabases at no charge through my hosts, but the WPMU install keeps maxing out. This is alot down to students not clearing spam!

I want to be able to bond more than one database (on different host IPs) to serve the installation. I've looked at HyperDB but can't get it to work.

```
$wpdb->add_database(array(
'host'     => DB_HOST,     // If port is other than 3306, use host:port.
'user'     => DB_USER,
'password' => DB_PASSWORD,
'name'     => DB_NAME,
));

$wpdb->add_database(array(
'host'     => '***.***.***.51',     // my second, blank database on a diff IP.
'user'     => 'USER2',     // a diff username.
'password' => DB_PASSWORD,     // the same password as in the master config.php.
'name'     => 'newdbase_2012',     // my second database name.
));
```

Any help would be really, really appreciated in either getting this to work, or pointing out a new way of doing it!!!

Comment: If the problem is spam, why don't you use Akismet, captchas, registred-only comments etc.?

Comment: If it's a spam problem, I'd also recommend using Akismet or some other method of preventing the spam from accumulating in the first place. The amount of space does not seem to be the direct problem in this case. Trying to hack your way into linking two databases together to avoid paying for additional space might be a violation of your terms of service from your host as well, they limit it to 150MB, and trying to bypass that by using multiple free databases could get all of your sites taken down. I'd tread softly.

Comment: I have got in place some spam filters and akismet, the issue tends to be on the older sites with that. It is also about the number of sites that are now being created.

Comment: @mastrianni that is a good shout on the terms of service. That isn't an issue here, I can create as many databased per domain hosting as I want, it is just the limit of each. Maybe them tring to contain their server sizes? not sure, but it's legit!

Comment: `can't get it to work` is not a good problem description. What debug steps did you take?